# iOS Date 12/24 hour formatting (Objective C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I need to convert a 12 Hour time format to 24 Hour format. Specifically the PM part of a date, as the API I communicate with only accepts 24-hour format.

Example:

`02:00 PM` needs to be converted to `14:00`.

`08:30 PM` needs to be converted to `20:30`.

I've tried several approaches and probably been close, but I can't seem to get it quite right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you need to use `NSDateFormatter` and convert the time format to 24 Hours format.

```
NSString *time12Hours = @"02:00 PM";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:time12Hours];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
NSString *time24Hours = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Comment: Example: value is "02:00 PM".

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:value];
                
NSLog(@" 12 hour date:  %@", date);

When I log this I get null. (Sorry for the missing code highlighting).

Comment: Your answer was helpful. I still needed to add the following to get it working:               NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
                [formatter setLocale:locale];

Comment: @Tatter That was need to set the local timezone, you have not reply here that you are not getting perfect time.

Answer (score 0):

iPhone format strings are in [Unicode format](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns). Behind the link is a table explaining what all the letters above mean so you can build your own.

You can try this website for find your format string [nsdateformatter.com](http://nsdateformatter.com) whit `NSDateFormatter`